# Android IntentService never called

Tags: android, android-service

I've got an IntentService that I want to start upon onCreate. It's a fire and forget that makes a call to a website and then (possibly) starts a download through downloadmanager. I don't believe that my service is being started, because I don't see any Log statements from it. I've got the service in my manifest, same package as main. It also does not show up in my logcat (another thread said it should).

onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Intent heartbeat = new Intent(this, Heartbeat.class);
    startService(heartbeat);
}
```

*I've also tried this.startService(heartbeat); and it also did not work.

manifest:

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service android:name=".Heartbeat" android:enabled="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

*with or without android:enabled flag makes no difference

start of IntentService:

```
public class Heartbeat extends IntentService
{
    public Heartbeat()
    {
        super("Heartbeat");
        Log.v("SUPER", "SUPER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.v("HERE", "HERE");
        //do other stuff
```

Neither of these log statements show up in console/logcat, and my service never hits the web server (this code was previously in an asynctask and was functioning). Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit - I do see a warning from tag ActivityManager in my all messages stating "Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.vs_1.Heartbeat }: not found". However, nearly every suggestion I've seen on that message has been to put  in manifest in the application tag, which I've already done.

Comment: I've also tried turning Heartbeat.class and .Heartbeat in Main/manifest respectively to their long names com.whatever, to no avail.

Comment: Your code is all right. I suppose you have sth wrong in log console ;) (are you sure filter for verbose (you call `Log.v()`) and your app set in console settings? do you use eclipse or standalone ddms?)

Comment: Very sure, I can add Log.v("AFTER", "AFTER"); on the line after startService, and I see that in logcat. I'm using eclipse. So if the code seems right, what are my options? I want to use IntentService because it seems like the perfect fit, but I guess I could put it back as an asynctask, which was working earlier today.

Comment: If your Heartbeat class is in fact `com.example.vs_1.Heartbeat` (i guess from warning: `act=com.example.vs_1.Heartbeat, not found`) then you should declare it in manifest as `<service android:name=".vs_1.Heartbeat" android:enabled="true"/>` if app package is `com.example`

Comment: Tried that as well, it doesn't work, but changes the warning slightly.  With name=".vs_1.Heartbeat" in manifest, the warning becomes "Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.vs_1/.MainActivity.Heartbeat }: not found. The / is new. Does that give any clues? I also tried doing a minimal case app, with no success, editing main post to include that.

Comment: Wait, why your service is inner class of activity??? you cannot point at non-static inner class in manifest

Comment: move service class to separate file: com.example.test_intent.Heartbeat and change in manifest to: `<service android:name=".Heartbeat" android:enabled="true"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the plot thickens!

"Unable to start service" is an error, even though it's marked as a warning.

It occurs because the system can't find a class that has the name that's listed. In this case,
it's com.example.vs_1.Heartbeat.

To be sure you have that class, you need a file Hearbeat.java that contains

package com.example.vs_1;

public class Heartbeat extends IntentService...

In your manifest, if your  element contains the attribute
package="com.example.vs_1", then you can say

Note the period (".") before "Heartbeat".

If you're using another value for "package", then you have to say

/com.example.vs_1.Heartbeat" where  is the value of "package".

It should be clear from this that you should choose a single main package name for your classes, and use the same name for the "package" value.

Comment: That was it, once I put it into another file Heartbeat.java, it worked. It seems odd to me that it wouldn't find it in the MainActivity.java file. I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but when I do I certainly will.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the main Activity is being started correctly? LogCat would show you error messages if the system couldn't start your IntentService. Also, these are "verbose" messages, so be sure that LogCat is set to show them. If you have LogCat set to "error", it won't show verbose messages.

Comment: As far as I know it's being started correctly. My app starts, and shows me my blank page. I can also do a Log.v("AFTER", "AFTER"); right after the start service and I see that output. I also realized that in my all messages, from tag ActivityManger, I see this warning (not error though...) "Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.vs_1.Heartbeat }: not found". Googling it though has brought no suggestions other than the ones I've seen. So I guess I've at least I've confirmed it's not starting correctly.